# PHP Remove specific space from string

Tags: php, laravel

```
$destination ="Hong Kong "
```

I want to remove the last space to become like this

```
$destination ="Hong Kong"
```

Comment: Laravel has a [rtrim](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-rtrim) helper, PHP has [rtrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), [`ltrim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) or [`rtrim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function.

`trim` removes the characters at the beginning and end of the string.
`ltrim`, only those at the beginning of the string.
and `rtrim` those at the end of the string.

In your case to delete the last space, you can do so :

```php
$destination = rtrim("Hong Kong "); //prints "Hong Kong"
```

Comment: Try not to answer duplicates. If the answer already exists on SO, don't add it again

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that it was a duplicate, I didn't pay attention. It is noted for the future.